# Is there a way to configure firebase timeout time ?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication

I noticed odd behavior with firebase.

When making a login request with no internet it takes a pretty long time for firebase to timeout and return an error in the completion handler.

Once the first timeout occurs firebase starts timing out after 1 second or 2.

I wanted to lower the timeout time for requests.

---

I know I can check for internet connection before making any firebase requests. 
But this does not solve all situations because the internet connection can cut out when the request is actually being sent.

In those odd cases the users will have to wait a long time and will probably exit the app thinking that it crashed.

I know that I can probably observe the internet connection and display some kind of icon to let the user know that the internet connection is cutting out. 
But this seems like a lot of work for something simple. 
Apple's networking api returns immediately when this occurs, it seems odd for firebase not to be able to handle something like this.

---

To summarize, I want to find a way to lower timeout time for firebase requests.

Or

Ideally make firebase return an error immediately after the internet connection cuts out.

Comment: If you are using something like Alamofire, may be you can set a reasonable time-out yourself?

Comment: @userx I'm using their iOS framework.

Comment: May be you could try creating a task in iOS for performing login to Firebase which would run for some time, and if that doesnt respond, you can cancel the task. Just another way to tackle it.

Comment: if you have used URlSession set its timeout **sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30.0** , it will timeout automatically if response is not received with In the time

Comment: @iosgeek the question has to do with firebase's ios api. I didn't create my own client in swift, I'm using their code and It seems like they don't support this.

Comment: @3366784 did you solve this problem?